# Windows with Layouts livesearchgridpanel Ext.js4

Tags: windows, extjs, grid, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have some grids already designed, but I have to include them in a [Windows Layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/window/layout.html). The **problem** is: The grids are enabled for [livesearchpanel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/grid/live-search-grid.html). How can I mantain this type of grid inside a window layout? Here there is no way to define the grid by a constructor, they're just items of a bigger constructor:

```
 Ext.create('widget.window', {
```

Where should I place the constructor:

```
Ext.create('Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel', {
```

?

I'm confused, any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it as an item in the window:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
    // ... window configuration

    ,layout: 'fit' // if you don't want other items

    ,items: [
        Ext.create('Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel', {...});
    ]
});
```

Don't do that if you extend the window class, however, or you'll get bitten if you try to create multiple instances of this window (because they'd be sharing one single instance of your grid component). Create an instance of you component during window initialization instead:

```
Ext.define('My.GridWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.Window'

    // ... window configuration

    ,layout: 'fit' // if you don't want other items

    ,initComponent: function() {

        this.items = [
            Ext.create('Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel', {...})
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: And if i should add two grids with livesearch? `[
            Ext.create('Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel', {...}),
            Ext.create('Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel', {...})
        ];` ?

Comment: Yup. But you'll also have to change the layout. Fit layout takes only the first item into account. VBoxLayout may be a good choice (see the docs for usage).